# Convert query from query builder t to Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

Hi all can you help me ?

I have query like this :

```
public function getByUser($userId,$activityId){
        return $journals = DB::table('personfamilies')
            ->join('journals','personfamilies.id','=','journals.person_id')
            ->join('journal_details','journals.id','=','journal_details.journal_id')
            ->where([
                ['user_id','=',$userId],
                ['activities_id','=',$activityId]
            ])
            ->get();
    }
```

how to convert to eloquent ?

model PersonFamily.php

```
public function relationship(){
    return $this->hasOne(Relationship::class,'id','relationship_id');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function journal(){
    return $this->hasMany(Journal::class,'id','id');
}
```

Model Journal.php

```
   public function jurnalDetails(){
            return $this->hasMany(JurnalDetail::class,'id');
        }

        public function personfamily(){
            return $this->belongsTo(PersonFamily::class,'person_id','journal_id');
        }
```

JournalDetail.php

```
public function journal(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Journal::class,'id');
    }
```

I've tried it like this, but it does not work correctly
```

````
return $journal = PersonFamily::where([
            ['user_id','=',$userId]
            ])
            ->with('journal','journal.jurnalDetails')
            ->get();
```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

Assuming you have Family, FamilyMember, Journal and JournalEntry Models

Family Model:

```
// A family has many family members
public function familyMember() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\FamilyMember');
}
```

FamilyMember Model:

```
// A family member belongs to exactly one family
public function family() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Family')
}

// A family member has exactly one journal
public function journal() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Journal');
}
```

Journal Model:

```
// A journal belongs to exactly one family member
public function familyMember() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\FamilyMember');
}

// A journal has many journal entries
public function journalEntries() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\JournalEntry');
}
```

JournalEntry Model:

```
// A journal entry belongs to exactly one journal
public function journal() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Journal');
}
```

Then your query becomes fairly straightforward:

```
// If you need the whole Family
$family = Family::find($familyId);
// If you need all the family members that belong to a family
$familyMembers = $family->familyMembers;
// If you are looking for a particular family member
$familyMember = FamilyMember::find($userId);
// If you need the journal for a family member
$journal = $familyMember->journal
// If you need all the journal entries in a particular journal
$journalEntries = $journal->journalEntries;
```

You can then pass these variables into your view and display them as required.

[See the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) to make more customized relationships in case your foreign keys are different.